# Why do I get errors running shell commands in rails console (irb)

Tags: ruby, shell, ls, rails-console

When I run a simple `ls` command from the Rails console, I'm getting this error:

```
$ rails c
irb(main):001:0> `ls`
script/rails: No such file or directory - ls
=> nil
```

I have the same error when using other commands such as `cd ~`. Can anyone tell me why the contents of the current folder are not displayed?

**UPDATE:**
After trying `exec('ls')`, this is the output, which is making me think it must be some local setting.

```
irb(main):001:0> exec('ls')
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - ls
    from (irb):1:in `exec'
    from (irb):1
    from     /[filepath]/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /[filepath]/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /[filepath]/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from /[filepath]/runtime/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /[filepath]/runtime/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Are you able to run `ls` outside of Ruby?

Comment: Yes, immediately after exiting the console, `ls` works as expected.

Comment: Have you looked at your `PATH` environment variable? Have you tried using the full path to `ls`?

Comment: Good point. `/bin` is in my PATH, but `/bin/ls` does work with the ruby console. Thanks for that advice. Pardon my lack of knowledge, but is there a separate path that rails loads for which I should probably update?

Comment: Perhaps your Rails config is messing with the path? I'd look in application.rb, environment.rb, and any initializers for clues. Also consider pulling out gems, especially any that were added recently.

Comment: Another thought: does it do the same thing in a non-rails IRB session?

Comment: Hmm, nothing looks out of the ordinary as far as app,env, and any initializers changing the path, but I could very well be wrong. Could you direct me on how to open a non-rails IRB session?

Comment: In the Rails app folder, run `irb`

Comment: It does indeed work just running IRB. So it must have something to do with the environment it's loading. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are now actually in an interactive ruby session (notice the `irb` in your prompt) within the context (so you can use the class, active record models, etc.) of your ruby on rails application.  Command that you issue should be ruby commands.  raw shell commands don't work here as is.

However you can use exec:

```
$ rails c
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.17)
2.0.0p247 :001 > exec('ls')
app     config.ru  doc      Gemfile.lock  log       README.rdoc  spec
config  db         Gemfile  lib           Rakefile  script       tmp
16:12:10 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/Dropnot/_/rails_apps/linker master
$
```

You can also use backicks (`) to run commands, i.e.

```
2.0.0p247 :007 > `ls`
=> "app\nconfig\nconfig.ru\ndb\ndoc\nGemfile\nGemfile.lock\nlib\nlog\nRakefile\nREADME.rdoc\nscript\nspec\ntmp\n"
```

Also `%x`:

```
2.0.0p247 :020 > %x('ls')
 => "app\nconfig\nconfig.ru\ndb\ndoc\nGemfile\nGemfile.lock\nlib\nlog\nRakefile\nREADME.rdoc\nscript\nspec\ntmp\n"
```

and `system`:

```
2.0.0p247 :021 > system("ls")
app     config.ru  doc      Gemfile.lock  log       README.rdoc  spec
config  db         Gemfile  lib           Rakefile  script       tmp
 => true
```

Comment: Please see my update. I'm guessing its a local configuration or environment problem.

Comment: hmmm, what happens if you just use irb instead of rails console ?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant +1 for system 'ls'. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!